# HTTP 303 redirect in Spring MVC *without tacking on JSESSIONID* and without touching any spring config

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

When using spring's RedirectView, it calls encodeRedirectURL which sneaks the JSESSIONID into the URL. I'd like to redirect without that happening.

Right now, I have:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/MyProfile")
public ModelAndView gotoMyProfile(HttpSession session) {
    return new ModelAndView(new RedirectView("/profile?id="+userid));
}
```

This works fine to redirect users to "/profile?id=4256", but it sticks ";JSESSIONID=F3D5AE8AED0F" in there, so I end up with "/profile;JSESSIONID=F3D5AE8AED0F?id=4256".

I'd like to have the code below, but I don't think HttpServletResponse is a valid return type for a RequestMapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/MyProfile")
public HttpServletResponse gotoMyProfile(HttpSession session, HttpServletResponse response) {
    response.setStatus(303);
    response.setHeader("Location", "/profile?id=" + userid);
    return response;
}
```

EDIT: Thanks for your answer, but I don't have access to the Spring security configuration. That's why I was trying the code above. I'm asking for a solution that can be done strictly in java.

Comment: No need to return the response. Type can just be void.

Answer (score 2):

You could set `disable-url-rewriting="true"` in the `<http>`.
But clients must use cookies if this attribute is set to true.